# Java - a way to find out whether collection is ordered or not

Tags: java, collections

I am looking for a way to find out in run-time, whether a collection is ordered or not. Any way to do this?

EDIT: I am sorry for wrongly asked question. I meant whether there is some general way to say HashMap does not store order of elements being inserted, where LinkedHashMap does.

Comment: By `ordered`, do you mean `sorted`?

Comment: what kind of data it contains ????

Comment: I don't think technically speaking a "Collection" can be said to be ordered since the general contract of Collection doesn't guarantee that items will stay in a consistent order, but List does, so presumably you mean List.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For elements that implement the `Comparable` interface, you can check to see if they are in their "natural" order.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isOrdered(Iterable<T> list) {
  Iterator<T> i = list.iterator();
  if (i.hasNext()) {
    T previous = i.next();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
      T current = i.next();
      if (previous.compareTo(current) > 0)
        return false;
      previous = current;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to define a `Comparator` that can compare your objects according to your definition of order, and pass that to the test.

```
public static <T> boolean isOrdered(Iterable<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
  Iterator<T> i = list.iterator();
  if (i.hasNext()) {
    T previous = i.next();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
      T current = i.next();
      if (c.compare(previous, current) > 0)
        return false;
      previous = current;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 for being generic. If you want to use this with an object that is already implements Comparable you want write some [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) (or does one exist in the JDK already?) that just calls `compare()` of the objects themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Using the lovely and popular [Guava libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it's a highly readable one-liner:

```
 return Ordering.natural().isOrdered(collection);
```

If your elements are ordered according to some other comparator, and not their natural ordering:

```
 return Ordering.from(comparator).isOrdered(collection);
```

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming it is a `List`*, this should do it :-)

It compares every item (except the last - it will be checked by the second last item) and checks whether the next item is smaller. If that is the case then it isn't sorted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < collection.size() - 1; i++)
{
    if (collection.get(i).compareTo(collection.get(i+1)) > 0)
    {
        // NOT SORTED

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 replace `>` with `compareTo()` and check if it is greater than 0.

Comment: Technically, only the List interface allows ordering.  So your test should check if the collection can be casted to List.

Comment: @jordan002: There are also other sorted collection types, i.e. the SortedSet and there could be any number of custom collection types that support sorting.